# При запуске утилиты crash: cannot find booted kernel -- please enter namelist argument

Tags: linux

Что делать? Debian-based дистр.

Comment: https://github.com/crash-utility/crash/issues/9

Comment: Спасибо! Сам, почему-то, проглядел эту инфу. Чтобы crash заработал на debian-based дистрибутиве, нужно выполнить: sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbg